# What are the 0x testnet endpoints?

Tags: 0x

I’m trying to test the 0x REST api, and can see the endpoints for the main nets, but what about the test nets? Specifically interested in endpoints for Polygon Mumbai and Goerli

Answer (score 1):

We currently support [Ropsten on Ethereum](https://ropsten.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=DAI&buyToken=WETH&buyAmount=19000000000000000000&slippagePercentage=0.01&gasPrice=29000000000).

What we recommend is for developers to create a local fork of the network with Ganache/HardHat and execute their testing against that using the live mainnet APIs.